# Load Testing and Benchmarking With siege vs wrk

Tags: benchmarking, performance-testing, stress-testing, siege, wrk

I have been looking around for tools that can help me to do load testing and benchmarking. I found a couple like:

- https://github.com/wg/wrk
- http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/
- https://github.com/rakyll/boom

I'm wondering if anyone has any experience with these tools and have any feedback pros vs cons of these tools. My load stress will include different test cases using DELETE, PUT, GET, POST, etc. headers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've used wrk and siege, siege is a really easy to use tool, but I'm not sure if you can test DELETE or PUT with siege.

Wrk can use provided lua script to generate requests, so DELETE and PUT won't be a problem. AND wrk is a tool that can overpower NGINX static file server, so I think it's fast enough for general purpose load testing.

I've never used boom or Yandex.tank suggested by @Direvius, basically because wrk is simple enough and fit our needs. But JMeter is too complex for me.

Answer (score 57):

**Load testing and benchmarking tools**

*Listed in alphabetical order.*

[ab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ApacheBench): slow and single threaded, written in C

[apib](https://github.com/apigee/apib): most of the features of ApacheBench (ab), also designed as a more modern replacement, written in C

[baloo](https://github.com/h2non/baloo): expressive end-to-end HTTP API testing made easy, written in Go (golang)

[baton](https://github.com/americanexpress/baton): HTTP load testing, written in Go (golang)

[bombardier](https://github.com/codesenberg/bombardier): fast crossplatform HTTP benchmarking tool, written in Go (golang)

[curl-loader](http://curl-loader.sourceforge.net/): performance loading of various application services and traffic generation, written in C

[drill](https://github.com/fcsonline/drill): HTTP load testing application inspired by Ansible syntax, written in Rust

[fasthttploader](https://github.com/hagen1778/fasthttploader): benchmark (kinda ab) with autoadjustment and charts based on fasthttp library, write in Go (golang)

[fortio](https://github.com/istio/fortio): load testing library and command line tool and web UI. Allows to specify a set query-per-second load and record latency histograms and other useful stats, write in Go (golang)

[gatling](http://gatling.io/): high performance load testing framework based on Scala, Akka and Netty, write in Scala

[go-wrk](https://github.com/tsliwowicz/go-wrk): HTTP benchmarking tool based in spirit on the excellent wrk tool (wg/wrk), write in Go (golang)

[goad](https://github.com/gophergala2016/goad): AWS Lambda powered, highly distributed, load testing tool, write in Go (golang)

[gobench](https://github.com/cmpxchg16/gobench): HTTP/HTTPS load testing and benchmarking tool, write in Go (golang)

[gohttpbench](https://github.com/parkghost/gohttpbench): ab-like benchmark tool run on multi-core cpu, write in Go (golang)

[hey](https://github.com/rakyll/hey): HTTP(S) load generator, ApacheBench (ab) replacement, formerly known as rakyll/boom, written in Go (golang)

[htstress](https://github.com/arut/htstress): multithreading high-load bechmarking services (>5K rps), written in C/Linux

[httperf](https://github.com/httperf/httperf): difficult configuration, slow and single threaded, written in C

[inundator](https://github.com/opsengine/inundator): simple and high-throughput HTTP flood program, written in C/Linux

[jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/): Apache JMeter™, pure application designed to load test performance both on static and dynamic resources, written in Java

[k6](https://github.com/loadimpact/k6): modern load testing tool scriptable in ES6 JS with support for HTTP/1.1, HTTP/2.0 and WebSocket, written in Go (golang)

[locust](https://locust.io/): easy-to-use, distributed load testing tool with real-time web UI. Simulates a swarm of concurrent users, the behavior of each of them is defined by your python code. Written in Python

[mgun](https://github.com/byorty/mgun): modern tool for load testing HTTP servers, written in Go (golang)

[pounce](https://github.com/X4/pounce): evented, but results fluctuate, it's sometimes faster than htstress, written in C

[siege](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/): slow and single threaded, written in C

[slapper](https://github.com/ikruglov/slapper): simple load testing tool with real-time updated histogram of request timings, written in Go (golang)

[slow_cooker](https://github.com/BuoyantIO/slow_cooker): load tester focused on lifecycle issues and long-running tests, service with a predictable load and concurrency level for a long period of time, written in Go (golang)

[sniper](https://github.com/lubia/sniper): powerful & high-performance http load tester, written in Go (golang)

[tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/): simulate stress users in order to test the scalability and performance of IP based client/server applications HTTP, WebDAV, SOAP, PostgreSQL, MySQL, LDAP and Jabber/XMPP servers, written in Erlang

[vegeta](https://github.com/tsenart/vegeta): HTTP load testing tool and library, written in Go (golang)

[weighttp](https://github.com/lighttpd/weighttp): multithreaded, but slower than htstress without keepalive, written in C

[wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk): multithreaded, written in C/Lua

[wrk2](https://github.com/giltene/wrk2): constant throughput, correct latency recording variant of wrk, written in C/Lua

[yandex-tank](https://github.com/yandex/yandex-tank): load and performance benchmark tool, written in Python/C|C++|Asm (phantom)

Descriptions are from [here](https://github.com/denji/awesome-http-benchmark).

Answer (score 2):

I've never used any of these, but I've heard some positive opinions about wrk.

I think, you should also try [Jmeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/), which is very popular, and maybe [Yandex.tank](https://github.com/yandex-load/yandex-tank), which is the tool we use at our LT department for most of our web-services.